# Get the name of the current route in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, routes

I know that in previous versions of Laravel you could fetch the name by calling the getCurrentRoute in the route class, but since 5.5 was released it still remains a mystery on how I can do this?

In previous versions, this is how I did it.

```
Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call the `currentRouteName` on the route class.

```
Route::currentRouteName();
```

Don't forget to use the class.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew there was still a simple way of doing it.